# Rendering 3-d lines in Java?

Tags: java, 3d, camera, 2d, rendering

Ok, I have a little problem: I'm trying to code an engine capable of rendering 3d lines onto a 2d plane, but I'm having some trouble with it.
I have a point3d class, which takes x y and z coords, a line3d class, which takes two point3d endpoints, and I have a world object containing an arraylist of line3d's. I also have point2d and line2d, which are just like their 3d counterparts, except that they lack a z coordinate.

Here's the render method:

```
public void render(){
    for(Line3d line : world.lines){ //for every 3d line in the world
        panel.l3d(line, world.main); //render that line
    }
    panel.repaint(); //repaint the graphic
}
```

Which calls upon the l3d method:

```
public void l3d(Line3d line, Camera view){
    Point2d start = p3Top2(line.start, view), end = p3Top2(line.end, view); //convert 3d points to 2d points
    if(start==null || end==null)return; //if either is null, return
    lineAbs(new Line2d(start, end)); //draw the line
}
```

Which calls upon p3Top2:

```
public Point2d p3Top2(Point3d point, Camera view){ //convert 3d point to 2d point on screen
    int relativeZed = point.z - view.z; //difference in z values between camera and point
    if(relativeZed <= 0)return null; //if it's behind the camera, return
    int sx, sy, ex, ey, tx, ty; //begin declaring rectangle formed from extending camera angle to the z coord of the point(angle of 1 = 90 degrees)
    sx = (int) (view.x - (width / 2) - relativeZed * (width * view.angle)); //starting x of rectangle
    ex = (int) (view.x + (width / 2) + relativeZed * (width * view.angle)); //ending x
    sy = (int) (view.y - (height / 2) - relativeZed * (height * view.angle)); //starting y
    ey = (int) (view.y + (height / 2) + relativeZed * (height * view.angle)); //ending y
    tx = point.x - sx; //difference between point's x and start of rectangle
    ty = point.y - sy; //same for y
    float px = (float)tx / (float)(ex - sx), py = (float)ty / (float)(ey - sy); //px and py are the ratios of the point's x/y coords compared to the x/y of the rectangle their in
    return new Point2d((int)(px * width), (int)(py * height)); //multiply it by the width and height to get positions on screen
}
```

And also on lineAbs:

```
public void lineAbs(Line2d line){
    Point2d start = line.start;
    Point2d end = line.end;
    if(start.x>end.x){
        start = line.end;
        end = line.start;
    }
    int y = start.y; //starting y point
    int white = 0xffffff;
    for(int x = start.x; x<end.x; x++){ //for each x in the line
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x > canvas.getWidth() || y > canvas.getHeight())continue; //if the point is outside of the screen, continue
        y += line.getSlope().slope; //increment y by the slope
        canvas.setRGB(x, y, white); //draw the point to the canvas
    }
}
```

'canvas' is a BufferedImage being drawn to the screen. With an arbitrary camera and angle of 1, as well as a few arbitrary lines thrown in, I do see each line, but they don't appear to be rendered properly. For example, when I have three point3d's as vertices, and three lines, each with a different combination of two of the points, the lines don't appear to meet at all, although each one is visible.

I suspect the issue is in my p3Top2, but I'm not sure where, can you tell?

Comment: I suspect it's actually `lineAbs`. `y` is an integer, but lines usually have non-integer slopes.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after posting, but it kinda looks like some of the lines actually have slopes of the wrong sign. Once I increase the Z of one of the line's points past 1, it looks like the line drawn changes from what should be a negative slope to a positive one.
EDIT: Hmm, maybe not. At the very least, making y a float made the lines look connected.